# How to reduce the length of Q# programs execution time?

Tags: programming, q#

In the released Q# documentation by Microsoft available at: [Quantum Development Kit Full State Simulator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/machines/full-state-simulator?view=qsharp-preview), it is written

> By default OpenMP uses all available hardware threads, which means that programs with small numbers of qubits will often run slowly because the coordination required will dwarf the actual work. This can be fixed by setting the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to a small number.

So I wonder how to do that as I couldn't find the solution of fixing `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to a small number in their documentation?

**Update:**
Following is the snippet of the my code which does the main job:

```
mutable numberOfObservedZeros = 0;

for (i in 1..firstLoop){

    for (j in 1..secondLoop){

        Set (qubit,Zero);

        Ry (0.3141, qubit);
        R1 (0.0, qubit); 

        if (M(qubit) == Zero){
             set numberOfObservedZeros += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

where `firstLoop` and `secondLoop` are passed to the operation containing the above block of code.

Comment: It's a good question - first, how many qubits are you operating on / how many threads is your machine / were you able to run the sample programs fine?

Comment: @C.Kang Currently, just two qubits are required.

Comment: how many threads is your machine / were you able to run the sample programs fine? Also, posting the code might help

Comment: @C.Kang The machine has got 4 CPU's each having 1 thread. I share a snippet of my code.

Comment: @C.Kang Please have a look.

Comment: What is "Set"? Also, doesn't this only require a singe qubit

Comment: @C.Kang `Set` operation sets the state of the qubit to `zero state` and it takes just one qubit.

Comment: Could you provide the code for that too? Are you following along this - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quickstart?view=qsharp-preview&tabs=tabid-python

Comment: @C.Kang Yes, that's the same as the Microsoft's one.

Comment: Then the Zero / qubit need to be reversed - the parameters are in the wrong order

Comment: @C.Kang I have defined it in a way that the order of the arguments are different but apart from that, its functionality and body is exactly the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103233/discussion-between-c-kang-and-coder).

Comment: Given that the quantum program listed in your question only uses a single qubit, I'd be surprised if setting OpenMP parallelization policies would affect that much. Can you provide a bit more detail about the performance issues that you're running into? Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisGranade As you can see, there is a nested loop inside another one. If there is just one loop in the code, then the execution time will be just some few seconds, but since here there are two loops the execution time increases considerably. For instance, if the values of `firstLoop` and `secondLoop` are 500 and 400 respectively, the whole number of iterations will be 200000. When I run the code it takes more than two-three minutes to finish!

Comment: Well, that's because the operation is being done 200,000 times - even if each operation was 0.1 seconds, that'd by 20,000 seconds (or 300 minutes!)
Realistically, 2-3 minutes is actually pretty fast (~150 seconds for 200,000 iterations, so each iteration takes 0.00075 seconds)

Comment: @C.Kang You opinion is correct, but imagine if 200,000 number of iterations are performed in any other classical programming languages such as C#, then it will be done very quickly, although I understand that the code is executed in the simulator framework Q# and the conditions are different so I was wondering if changing the value of `OMP_NUM_THREADS ` or any other approach would help.

Comment: If you're just looking for the amplitudes, you could instead use [DumpRegister](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.diagnostics.dumpregister?view=qsharp-preview) and only run the nested loops once?

Comment: @C.Kang Thanks. I think this is a good suggestion to try.